# pycharm Professional 2017.1 step tools are grayed out. I've tried everything but voodoo

Tags: pycharm

Somebody said to set breakpoints. Didn't help. 
Step Over, Step Into all grayed out.
Aternately can someone suggest a Python IDE?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your project. Without any details it is hard to determine what is causing the problem.

Comment: Shot in the dark: You can have multiple debuggers going at the same time on different tabs. You have X debugger session running, but you are looking at the tab for debugging session Y.